# Scala filter return only one (or specific number) of results

Tags: scala

What is the best Scala idiomatic approach to verify that filter returns only one results (or specific amount in that matter), and if the amount correct, to continue with it?

For example:

```
 val myFilteredListWithDesiredOneItem = unfilteredList
    .filter(x => x.getId.equals(something))
    .VERIFY AMOUNT
    .toList
```

Comment: Have you had a look at `.collectFirst` ?

Comment: @cchantep yes, it have partial function passed as an argument. I was curious if there is some alternative to that.

Comment: Have you tried it? Do you find any issue with?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the number is wrong?

Comment: @cchantep checked it, no issues with that :)

Comment: @Dima If the number is wrong, it's a smell for a serious error in the alg, will throw an exception in the verification point or from where this code will be called . What do you think?

Comment: Check the length and branch in an if, or wrap the list in an Either (with a Left value when the list in wrong and a bonus message).  With an Either, you can then call map to access the result when it's correct (or match when you're ready to handle the error case).  That seems very idiomatic.  In general, substituting Either (or Option) for thrown exceptions or even for branching is very idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this for a list of type `T`,

```
val myFilteredListWithDesiredOneItem = {
  val xs = unfilteredList.filter(x => x.getId.equals(something))
  if (xs.size == n) xs.toList
  else List.empty[T]
}
```

Not a oneliner, the code remains simple none the less.

Answer (score 0):

Try a match with guards, perhaps?

```
list.filter(...) match {
    case Nil => // empty
    case a if (a.size == 5) => // five items
    case b@(List(item1, item2) => // two (explicit) items
    case _ => // default
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Something like this perhaps:

```
Option(list.filter(filterFunc))
  .filter(_.size == n) 
  .getOrElse(throw new Exception("wrong size!"))
```